# Dropbox API for PHP gives error

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a file in chunks via Dropbox's API for PHP.
This is my code: This gives out the folowing error: 
First few chunks are uploaded and then I get this error:-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dropbox\Exception_NetworkIO' with message 'Erro
r executing HTTP request: Failed to connect to api-content.dropbox.com port 443:
 Connection refused' in /home/yashtk1/public_html/dropbox/Dropbox/Curl.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home/yashtk1/public_html/dropbox/Dropbox/Client.php(721): Dropbox\Curl->exec
()
#1 /home/yashtk1/public_html/dropbox/Dropbox/Client.php(602): Dropbox\Client->_c
hunkedUpload(Array, '`S\xCDb0\x80`\xA0\xD3\xB7\xEA\x07\xF1\xF7\xB4...')
#2 /home/yashtk1/public_html/dropbox/Dropbox/Client.php(437): Dropbox\Client->ch
unkedUploadContinue('jB2ZQWVyzMQgsX4...', 41943040, '`S\xCDb0\x80`\xA0\xD3\xB7\x
EA\x07\xF1\xF7\xB4...')
#3 /home/yashtk1/public_html/dropbox/Dropbox/RequestUtil.php(278): Dropbox\Clien
t->Dropbox\{closure}()
#4 /home/yashtk1/public_html/dropbox/Dropbox/Client.php(438): Dropbox\RequestUti
l::runWithRetry(3, Object(Closure))
#5 /home/yashtk1/public_html/dropbox/Dropbox/Client.php(381): Dropbox\Client->_u
ploadFileChunked('/ahmd1.zip', Object(Dropbox\WriteMode), Resource i in /home/ya
shtk1/public_html/dropbox/Dropbox/Curl.php on line 69
```

My script:-

```
<?php
echo "hi";
set_time_limit(0);

# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
require_once "Dropbox/autoload.php";

use \Dropbox as dbx;

$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("config");


$f = fopen("ahmd1.zip", "rb");

$dbxClient = new dbx\Client("Access code", "PHP-Example/1.0");

$mode = dbx\WriteMode::add();

$chunk = $dbxClient->uploadFileChunked("/ahmd1.zip", $mode, $f);

print_r($chunk);

//uploadFileChunked( string $path, Dropbox\WriteMode $writeMode, resource $inStream, integer|null $numBytes = null, integer|null $chunkSize = null );

fclose($f);
?>
```

Please can anyone point out the mistake ?

Comment: Which one is line 381?

Comment: @Mureinik I updated the question with the code.

Comment: Cross-linking with the Dropbox API forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=120776.

Comment: @YashSodha : How did you resolved the problem? I am also facing the same.